# CYPHER - Return linked nodes in original order

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm really enjoying the potential power of Graph & Cypher query language (coming from an RDBMS background), but I'm really struggling to get my head around some of the concepts involved!

What I'm attempting to do feels like it should be relatively simple... I have a very simple series of five nodes with a parent -> child relationship. In my mind, if I was to query for this, each node should be returned in the appropriate order. Here is the query as it stands -

```
MATCH p = (:Folder)-[:CHILD*]->(f:Folder { id: '1d05a36b-a67f-3fe7-a13a-6f12b1a38d26' })

WITH NODES(p) AS folders

UNWIND folders as folder

WITH folder RETURN DISTINCT folder
```

Here is what the result of my query looks as a graph -

[image]

However, once queried with the above query and getting the physical response, it's being represented in the following order -

- Folder 4
- Folder 5
- Folder 3
- Folder 2
- Folder 1

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"folder"                                                              │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"Folder 4","created_at":"2019-10-07 12:14:07","id":"5b6b3316-e│
│e57-3ca5-8f62-bed81b09ab7b","updated_at":"2019-10-07 12:14:07","parent│
│_folder_id":"2dabecfc-2018-3876-bc01-28922ebbb09d"}                   │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Folder 5","created_at":"2019-10-07 12:14:07","id":"1d05a36b-a│
│67f-3fe7-a13a-6f12b1a38d26","updated_at":"2019-10-07 12:14:07","parent│
│_folder_id":"5b6b3316-ee57-3ca5-8f62-bed81b09ab7b"}                   │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Folder 3","created_at":"2019-10-07 12:14:07","id":"2dabecfc-2│
│018-3876-bc01-28922ebbb09d","updated_at":"2019-10-07 12:14:07","parent│
│_folder_id":"a1344b93-ab69-398d-81c5-cb901ff8f0b0"}                   │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Folder 2","created_at":"2019-10-07 12:14:07","id":"a1344b93-a│
│b69-398d-81c5-cb901ff8f0b0","updated_at":"2019-10-07 12:14:07","parent│
│_folder_id":"a22eca18-57fd-364d-b965-d850724131e8"}                   │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Folder 1","created_at":"2019-10-07 12:14:07","id":"a22eca18-5│
│7fd-364d-b965-d850724131e8","updated_at":"2019-10-07 12:14:07"}       │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

How can I possibly go about ordering this data or does my query need a complete rewrite?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this query :

```
MATCH p = (n:Folder)-[:CHILD*]->(f:Folder { id: '1d05a36b-a67f-3fe7-a13a-6f12b1a38d26' })
WHERE NOT ()-[:CHILD]->(n)
WITH NODES(p) AS folders
RETURN folders
```

I think that your problem comes from the fact that there are multiple paths `p`, and that's why you used the `distinct`.

Dont forget that if you ask the database to find the pattern `(n:Folder)-[:CHILD*]->(f:Folder { id: '1d05a36b-a67f-3fe7-a13a-6f12b1a38d26' })`, the database will give you all the possibilities, so in your example :

- `F4 -> F5`
- `F3 -> F4 -> F5`
- `F2 -> F3 -> F4 -> F5`
- `F1 -> F2 -> F3 -> F4 -> F5`

And if you do a `distinct` on this result set, yes you have the result `F4, F5, F3, F2, F1`.

Comment: and it's ats simple as that! So the `NOT` clause is the fix here but I don't understand exactly how that resolves it? Is that essentially saying get the last folder all the way to the parent folder, but don't match any other relationships to the last folder? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Here I'm saying to the database that the node `n` is the root node of your path (ie. whitout any incoming `CHILD` relationship). So there only one matching path, not many like I described in the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It makes sense now - I had no idea it returned many possibilities!